# Preferred way of writing vertical media queries with Sass' Breakpoint Extension

Tags: sass, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

With the Sass extension Breakpoint, is there a preferred way to write vertical media queries that only have a single argument for the query value?

Here's an example of what I'd like to ultimately accomplish:

```
@media (max-height: 50em) {
  .item {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Or, should I just do a plain, "on-the-fly" media query for these styles like such:

```
.item {
  @media (max-height: 50em) {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Is this something that could possibly be handled with a variable?

My styles are "mobile first", so all of the other media queries on this site use Breakpoint's default "min-width" setting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$vertical: 'max-height' 50em;

.item {
  @include breakpoint($vertical) {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

You can also include height queries with other queries as follows:

```
$mixed: 15em ('max-height' 50em);

.item {
  @include breakpoint($mixed) {
     font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Comment: To expand on Snug's answer, you can use any media query feature and value pair as a breakpoint value. `min-width  15em`, `max-height 10vh`, `orientation portrait`, `color 8`: any media query feature value pair can be a breakpoint pair.

Comment: Thanks, Snugug & RobW! My syntax ended up looking like this: `@include breakpoint('max-height' 50em) {styles:here}`